# When does $PAP = (Q \otimes R) A (Q \otimes R)$ imply $P$ is a tensor product, for orthogonal projections $P$, $Q$, and $R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products, positive-semidefinite, projection-matrices

Suppose $A$ is a positive semi-definite operator on $V \otimes W$ such that $\operatorname{tr}(A) > 0$, where $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional complex vector spaces.
Let $P$ be an orthogonal projection on $V \otimes W$, and let $Q$ and $R$ be orthogonal projections on $V$ and $W$, respectively.
If we have
$$PAP = (Q \otimes R) A (Q \otimes R) ,$$
does $P$ necessarily have the form of a tensor product $P = S \otimes T$ for some $S$ and $T$?

In the special case that $A$ is positive definite, $P = Q \otimes R$.
I am interested in any similar statement that can be made under weaker conditions on the positivity of $A$.

Comment: How did you reach that conclusion in the case that $A$ is positive definite?

Comment: @BenGrossmann from [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/25767/16701) answer to another question I asked

Comment: Thanks! In any case, the general statement is false. As a counterexample, consider
$$
P = A = \pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0}, \quad P = Q = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}.
$$

Comment: We have $(A^{1/2}PA^{1/2})^2=(A^{1/2}(Q\otimes R)A^{1/2})^2$. By the uniqueness of positive semidefinite square root, $A^{1/2}PA^{1/2}=A^{1/2}(Q\otimes R)A^{1/2}$. Therefore $P=Q\otimes R$ when $A$ is positive definite. Yet, as shown in the Ben's comment above, $P$ isn't necessary a tensor product if $A$ is merely positive semidefinite.